# DiscordJS v14 - Command Handler

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command handle function, and this is my code, however it gives me an error in the console.

Sometimes when I go and reload the bot, the error doesn't populate, but it won't show the slash command. Other times, I get the error listed below.

```js
const chalk = require("chalk");
const fs = require("fs");
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.handleCommands = async () => {
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands");
    for (const folder of commandFolders) {
      const commandFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

      const { commands, commandArray } = client;
      for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        commandArray.push(command, command.data.toJSON());
        console.log(
          chalk.white("Command: ") +
            chalk.cyan.bold`${command.data.name} ` +
            chalk.white("has successfully loaded.")
        );
      }
    }

    const clientId = "(Client_ID)";
    const rest = new REST({ version: "10" }).setToken(
      process.env.DISCORD_DEV_TOKEN
    );

    try {
      console.log("Started refreshing application (/) commands.");

      await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId), {
        body: client.commandArray,
      });

      console.log("Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Here's the error.

```
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/**/Discord Bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:659:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/**/Discord Bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:458:14)
    at async REST.request (/home/**/Discord Bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:902:22)
    at async Client.client.handleCommands (/home/**/Discord Bot/src/functions/handlers/handleCommands.js:35:7) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: { '0': [Object] },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/(Client_ID)/commands'
}
```

I've attempted to debug it and follow the documentation from the Discord.JS website, but that doesn't even resolve the issue.

I currently have just the typical ping command, and here's the code for that.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Return's the bot's ping!"),

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const message = await interaction.deferReply({
      fetchReply: true,
    });
    const newMessage = `API Latency: ${client.ws.ping}\n Client Ping: ${
      message.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp
    }`;
    await interaction.editReply({
      content: newMessage,
    });
  },
};
```

Is anyone able to share where I'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was within `commandArray.push`.

I had it written out as

```js
commandArray.push(command, command.data.toJSON());
```

When it needed to be

```js
commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
```